# civicrm login form for individual users

Tags: wordpress, user-account

How to create a login for individual users in civicrm using WordPress (like membership login)?
Can anyone say how to create it? For this below screenshot i want to create login for users.

[image]

Comment: You should include the your civicrm version. Also, have you done any research on this yourself such as read the User and Admin guide (http://gitbook.civicrm.org/)

Answer (score 5):

1) Create/Edit a profile... In the advance settings:

WordPress user account registration option? = Account Creation required

2) In the profile listing. click More > User Profile Create Mode

This page (for a non-logged in user) should have account (login) creation.

Comment: Also make sure the WP settings have User Registration enabled or the login/registration fields will no appear even if enabled by the profile.